# Sort array objects by property value in specific order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array of objects that I'd like to sort using each object's property value compared against an ordered list of corresponding values.

Let's say I have this array of strings; food groups:

```
[ 'protein',
  'dairy',
  'fruit',
  'vegetable' ]
```

And I also have an array of objects, food items, each belonging to one of the former food groups by the property `group`:

```
[
  { group: 'vegetable', name: 'broccoli' },
  { group: 'protein', name: 'beef' },
  { group: 'fruit', name: 'apple' },
  { group: 'vegetable', name: 'peas' },
  { group: 'dairy', name: 'cheese' },
  { group: 'protein', name: 'tofu' },
  { group: 'vegetable', name: 'bell pepper' },
  { group: 'dairy', name: 'milk' },
  { group: 'fruit', name: 'grapes' },
  { group: 'protein', name: 'chicken' },
]
```

Given the order of the food groups in the first array, how can I sort the food items using their object `group` properties, to result in this:

```
[
  { group: 'protein', name: 'beef' },
  { group: 'protein', name: 'tofu' },
  { group: 'protein', name: 'chicken' },
  { group: 'dairy', name: 'cheese' },
  { group: 'dairy', name: 'milk' },
  { group: 'fruit', name: 'apple' },
  { group: 'fruit', name: 'grapes' },
  { group: 'vegetable', name: 'broccoli' },
  { group: 'vegetable', name: 'peas' },
  { group: 'vegetable', name: 'bell pepper' },
]
```

While I'm doing this in Javascript, I'm sure this would be more or less the same across a few languages.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `forEach` & `filter` array method. Iterate over the `food groups` & for each element filter out the matched element from the `group`, & store in a new array

```js
var order = ['protein',
  'dairy',
  'fruit',
  'vegetable'
]

var orgArry = [{
    group: 'vegetable',
    name: 'broccoli'
  },
  {
    group: 'protein',
    name: 'beef'
  },
  {
    group: 'fruit',
    name: 'apple'
  },
  {
    group: 'vegetable',
    name: 'peas'
  },
  {
    group: 'dairy',
    name: 'cheese'
  },
  {
    group: 'protein',
    name: 'tofu'
  },
  {
    group: 'vegetable',
    name: 'bell pepper'
  },
  {
    group: 'dairy',
    name: 'milk'
  },
  {
    group: 'fruit',
    name: 'grapes'
  },
  {
    group: 'protein',
    name: 'chicken'
  },
];
var newArray = [];
order.forEach(function(item) {
  return orgArry.filter(function(groupName) {
    if (groupName.group === item) {
      newArray.push(groupName)
    }
  })
});

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
array.sort( (foodA, foodB) =>
  groups.indexOf( foodA.group ) - groups.indexOf( foodB.group )
)
```

My example is in ES6, but could easily be rewritten in older versions. Here is a reference to the `sort` function - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Thanks Hugo! Would you be able to explain what's happening here?

Comment: The sort function will iterate over the array and compare 2 items at a time. A and B. It then repositions the items based on the value returned by the function you provide. If it returns lower than 0, it will sort A, B. If it is greater than 0, it will sort B, A. So I am getting the position of both foods within the group array, and comparing against each other.

Comment: So for example: If A is a Dairy and B is a Vegetable, their respective indexes in the groups array are 1 and 3. So returning (1 - 3) will put A in front of B.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your array using `array#sort` and finding the index of the `group` as it exists in the `order` array, but sorting won't be stable.

```js
var orders = [ 'protein', 'dairy', 'fruit', 'vegetable' ],
    data = [ { group: 'vegetable', name: 'broccoli' }, { group: 'protein', name: 'beef' }, { group: 'fruit', name: 'apple' }, { group: 'vegetable', name: 'peas' }, { group: 'dairy', name: 'cheese'}, { group: 'protein', name: 'tofu' }, { group: 'vegetable', name: 'bell pepper' }, { group: 'dairy', name: 'milk' }, { group: 'fruit', name: 'grapes' }, { group: 'protein', name: 'chicken' } ];
data.sort((a,b) => orders.indexOf(a.group) - orders.indexOf(b.group))
console.log(data);
```

To have a stable sort, you can try the below implementation.

```js
var orders = [ 'protein', 'dairy', 'fruit', 'vegetable' ],
    data = [ { group: 'vegetable', name: 'broccoli' }, { group: 'protein', name: 'beef' }, { group: 'fruit', name: 'apple' }, { group: 'vegetable', name: 'peas' }, { group: 'dairy', name: 'cheese'}, { group: 'protein', name: 'tofu' }, { group: 'vegetable', name: 'bell pepper' }, { group: 'dairy', name: 'milk' }, { group: 'fruit', name: 'grapes' }, { group: 'protein', name: 'chicken' }],
    result = data.map(({group},i) => ({item:orders.indexOf(group), index: i}))
                .sort((a,b) => a.item - b.item || a.index - b.index)
                .map(({index}) => data[index]);
    
console.log(result);
```